# Как сделать знаменатель для формулы "перестановки с повторениями"?

Tags: pascal, комбинаторика

Надеюсь на помощь в моем вопросе.
Итак, существует процедура, в ней мне необходимо посчитать значение знаменателя в формуле перестановок с повторениями.

````
```procedure k_perest(n: integer; var k:real);
var
l,i,j,k1: integer;
x,k0:string;
z,pr:real;
begin
k:=0;
k1:=0;
pr:=1;
for i:=1 to n do
begin
for j:=1 to n do
if (a[i] = a[j]) then k1:=k1+1;
factorial(k1,k);
z:=k;
pr:=pr*k;
k1:=0;
end;
k:=pr;
end; ```
````

Сейчас приведу функцию факториал:

````
```procedure factorial(n: integer; var f: real);
var
  ft: real;
  i: integer;
begin
  ft := 1;
  for i := 1 to n do
    ft := ft * i;
  f := ft
end; ```
````

Число получается не то, которое необходимо. Допустим, есть три элемента, два из них повторяются. Знаменатель должен быть равен двум, а он равен 4. Я понимаю, что это из-за того, что количество сначала считается для первого повторяющегося элемента, потом для второго, и их произведение равно четырем. Будьте добры помочь.

Comment: А что такое перестановки с повторениями? Ну просто чтобы быть уверенным, что имеется в виду одно и то же...

Comment: @MBo перестановки с повторениями это выходящая формула из формулы перестановок. Если перестановки из N элементов - это N!, то перестановки с повторениями имеют немного отличную суть. В числителе формулы перестановки с повторениями N! остается, но теперь появляется знаменатель. Считается количество каждого элемента и возводится в факториал. Например, если слово МОЛОТОК, тогда К(М)=1, К(О)=3, К(Л)=1, К(Т)=1, К(К)=1
Таким образом, 7! делим на 1!*3!*1!*1!*1!

Comment: Вот я и удивился, что в заголовке функции только аргументы n и k... Кроме n, нужен ещё **массив** счётчиков

Comment: @MBo я пробовал сделать с массивом счетчиков, но ничего не получилось и значение оставалось 0. Посмотрел Вашу функцию с динамическим массивом. Это, я так понимаю, массив счетчиков? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Да, массив счётчиков. Не динамический, а открытый (может принимать и статический, и динамический массив, и сформированный по месту)

Comment: Гм, вы хотите отношение факториалов считать в лоб? Ну, если у вас значения небольшие, то оно конечно...

Comment: @MBo светит ошибку, что нет перегруженной подпрограммы с такими типами параметров.

Comment: @Harry числа будут небольшие, в данном случае, максимум 6!, не больше. Да там и нет цели получить для больших факториалов, там цель сам алгоритм получить.

Comment: @IBuyPower31 Пишите в комментариях к ответу, а не здесь. [Однако работает](https://ideone.com/0wUktC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function prep(n: Integer; reps: array of integer): longint;
var
   i, k: integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
  for i := 2 to n do
     Result := Result * i; 
  for i := Low(reps) to High(reps) do
      for k := 2 to reps[i] do
          Result := Result div k  
end;

Writeln(prep(7, [2,3,2]));
```

Comment: В PascalABC отказывается работать, что огорчает(. В строке prep:=prep*i ошибка "Нет перегруженной подпрограммы".

Comment: Ну c этим чудом я не знаю, где проверить. Принцип решения-то понятен? На что ругается?

Comment: Понятно. Внутри функции все `prep` замените на `Result`. Я написал по-старинке, т.к. версия Паскаля не упоминалась

Comment: Мое почтение. Спасибо Вам огромное.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю так будет и понятнее и полезнее. Сделано на PascalABC.Net 3.7.1

```
function Factorial(const n: integer): real;
var
    i: integer;
    f: real;
begin
    if (n = 0) then f := 1
    else if(n > 0) then begin
        f := 1;
        for i := 2 to n do
            f := f * i;
    end
    else writeln('n<0');
    
    Factorial := f;
end;

function PermutationsWithRepetitions(const repetitions: array of integer): real;
var
    i, n: integer;
    kf: real;
begin
    n := 0;
    kf := 1;
    for i := Low(repetitions) to High(repetitions) do
    begin
        n := n + repetitions[i];
        kf := kf * Factorial(repetitions[i]);
    end;
    
    PermutationsWithRepetitions := kf / Factorial(n);
end;

var
    m1: array of integer := (2, 3, 2);
    m2: array of integer := (7, 3, 3);
    m3: array of integer := (11, 12, 13);

begin
    Writeln(PermutationsWithRepetitions(m1));
    Writeln(PermutationsWithRepetitions(m2));
    Writeln(PermutationsWithRepetitions(m3));
end.
```

Защита от дурака прописана не везде